# Animate resizing of ImageView to size of another ImageView

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a picture that I want to animate and move to another ImageView location.

Currently this is what I'm doing :

```
                v.animate()
                    .scaleX(??)
                    .scaleY(??)
                    .x(target.x)
                    .y(target.y)
                    .setDuration(1000)
                    .start()
```

My question is how can I calculate the correct scale factor for x and y? If I set the layout params equal to the target's layout params, then it works fine but it isn't animated. I've tried dividing the width and height of the source image with the target image, but it hasn't been giving me the correct scale.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are both of your image view in the same layout activity?

Comment: @HarshilShah Yeah, and my code to move the ImageView to the target works correctly - I just want the resizing of the image to have an animation rather than abruptly changing

Comment: The default value of scaleX and scaleY is `1` and it represents `100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a float value for the ratios between the two images:

```
float w_ratio = (targetImage.getMeasuredWidth() - sourceImage.getMeasuredWidth()) / sourceImage.getMeasuredWidth();
float h_ratio = (targetImage.getMeasuredHeight() - sourceImage.getMeasuredHeight()) / sourceImage.getMeasuredHeight();

// then animate:

v.animate().scaleXBy(w_ratio).scaleYBy(h_ratio).setDuration(1000);

// Don't forget to reset the size later if needed, using:

v.setScaleX(1.0f);
v.setScaleY(1.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution will be to get the actual width and height of the images via getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight(), and then doing division to compute the scale factor. Note, that using getWidth() and getHeight() is not a good option, as they contain information on width and height (e.g. integer value of MATCH_PARENT), not the final computed value. Also note, that measured with and height is available after UI was laid out. If your animation must be done on activity creation, you must trigger it in onWindowFocusChanged, at this time layout sizes are already computed (if I remember correctly).

```
imageViewToBeChanged
    .animate()
    .scaleX(targetImageView.getMeasuredWidth() / imageViewToBeChanged.getMeasuredWidth())
    .scaleY(targetImageView.getMeasuredHeight() / imageViewToBeChanged.getMeasuredHeight())
    .x(target.x)
    .y(target.y)
    .setDuration(1000)
    .start()
```

**EDIT**

Also, I am not sure how much scaling will affect the quality of image inside ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

To get the x and y position of your target imageView write the following code.

```
    x = imageViewObject.getLeft(); 
    y = imageViewObject.getTop();
```

To animate you need to make the following changes in your code

```
v.animate()
                .scaleX(0) // This will be your initial x position of your imageView
                .scaleY(0) // This will be your initial y position of your imageView
                .x(x)      // This will be the x position of your target imageView
                .y(y)      // This will be the y position of your target imageView
                .setDuration(1500)
                .start()
```

Initially, for testing purposes increase the duration so you can notice the animation and can make necessary changes if required.